# Change certain column order for certain row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change the order of certain column in certain row.
The dataframe looks like this.

| movieStream | optin_1 | musicStream | optin_2 | DramaStream | optin_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |
| netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |
| **hulu** | **no** | **netflix** | **yes** | **spotify** | **no** |
| netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |

I want to reorder the bold part along with the others in the same column like this:

| movieStream | optin_1 | musicStream | optin_2 | DramaStream | optin_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |
| netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |
| **netflix** | **yes** | **spotify** | **no** | **hulu** | **no** |
| netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |

I don't know it's specific index number...and I also don't how many mixed rows going to be in this Dataframe.

Comment: are you still stuck?

Comment: your code works thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easy and worst solution I can think of using apply.

1. Create a tuple of `stream` and `optin` pairs.
2. Order by the `key_order` list. Then convert the ordered list of tuples back to single list(flattening) 3) Return that list by converting it to `pandas Series`.

---

```
key_order = ['netflix', 'spotify','hulu']

def order_func(row):
    tup = list(zip(*[iter(row.values)]*2))
    sort_tup = (sorted(tup, key = lambda x: key_order.index(x[0])))
    li = [i for sub in sort_tup for i in sub]
    return pd.Series(li, index=row.index)

df = df.apply(order_func, axis=1)
```

**df:**

|  | movieStream | optin_1 | musicStream | optin_2 | DramaStream | optin_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |
| 1 | netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |
| 2 | netflix | yes | spotify | no | hulu | no |
| 3 | netflix | yes | spotify | yes | hulu | yes |

Comment: Thank you !! It works. I'm really appreciate it. Pygirl, you're the best.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only one value for each category (movie, music, drama), this code should work. Added comments for clarity.

```
# Load data to dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Filter out wrong df (to do less loops) - you can omit this step and just proceed with loop below
wrong_dfs = df.loc[(df['movieStream'] != "netflix") | (df['musicStream'] != "spotify") | (df['DramaStream'] != "hulu")]

# Setting proper order (from left to right)
order = ["netflix", "spotify", "hulu"]

# Working on raw list and indexes. Probably can be achieved with some pandas magic, but here is simple/easy to understand version of it ;)
for index, rows in wrong_dfs.iterrows():
    raw_row = rows.tolist()
    new_row = []
    for item in order:
        start_idx = raw_row.index(item)
        new_row += raw_row[start_idx:start_idx+2]
    df.loc[index] = new_row
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. You saved my day!!